# Check Url in robots.txt

Tags: python, parsing, robots.txt

I need to check if a certain URL in the robots.txt file is available for crawling by a certain agent.

I'm using

```
import urllib.robotparser
rp = urllib.robotparser.RobotFileParser("https://rus-teplici.ru/robots.txt")
rp.read()
print(rp.can_fetch("*", "https://rus-teplici.ru/"))
print(rp.can_fetch("*", "https://rus-teplici.ru/search/?q=fd"))
```

But the parser does not understand the characters * ? $. That's why the error

It doesn't understand strings such as:

```
Disallow: *set_filter=
```

URL
https://rus-teplici.ru/catalog/teplitsy-polikarbonat/?arrFilter_2_MIN=990&arrFilter_2_MAX=85990&set_filter=
will be TRUE.
Because it doesn't handle characters in robots.txt:
*
?

I looked - what it sees in robots.txt

```
Disallow: /%2Abitrix
Disallow: /%2Aindex.php
Disallow: %2Aset_filter%3D**
```

And it should see

```
Disallow: /*bitrix
Disallow: /*index.php
Disallow: *set_filter=*
```

Comment: And the message error is?

Comment: What is the text of the error message?

Comment: added a text in the question